Expressions in C. Are assignments expressions despite semicolons?
I am currently learning C and in one slide the professor states that Semicolons added to an expression makes it a statement. While on the other hand it mentioned that all assignments are expressions. Even if those assignments take extra lines and has to be seperated by semicolons.
See here:
    int a,b,c;
    a = b = c = 10;

    int a,b,c;
    b = 2; 
    c = 3;
    a = b + c;

Would these be considered all expressions? or statements
Tried looking through resources and got conflicting answers


C11 Standard 6.5.1 An expression is a sequence of operators and operands that specifies computation of a value, or that designates an object or a function, or that generates side effects, or that performs a combination thereof. The value computations of the operands of an operator are sequenced before the value computation of the result of the operator.


C11 Standard 6.8.2 A statement specifies an action to be performed. Except as indicated, statements are executed in sequence.

So in a = b = c = 42; we have 3 assignment expressions and 1 statement.
The expressions are a = <something>, b = <something>, and c = 42. (cf C11 6.5.16)
The statement is equivalent to the English sentence "Set a, b, and c to 42."


I am currently learning C and in one slide the professor states that Semicolons added to an expression makes it a statement.

Yes, a complete expression followed by a semicolon is an "expression statement", which is one of the several categories of statement recognized by C.

While on the other hand it mentioned that all assignments are expressions.

That can be interpreted in a manner that is true, but it is potentially confusing.  In C, = is an infix operator, much like + and / are. Combining it with valid left and right operands, such as in x = 1, forms an expression, just as in x + 1.  In this sense, yes, every assignment is an expression.
Every expression can be evaluated to produce a value, which in an assignment expression is the value assigned.  But assignment expressions are somewhat special in that they also have a side effect of updating the value of the object appearing as the left operand.

Even if those assignments take extra lines and has to be seperated by semicolons.

That doesn't make sense.  An assignment expression can be spread over multiple lines:
y
   =
      42

But if you append a semicolon then that is not part of the expression, and the expression does not continue past it.  You have thereby formed an expression statement.
But you can put statements one after the other, so this ...

b = 2; 
c = 3;
a = b + c;


... is three expression statements, each one containing a separate (full) assignment expression.
On the other hand, this ...

a = b = c = 10;

... is one expression statement, containing a single, more complex full expression involving some sub-expressions.  Because the = operator associates right-to-left, it is equivalent to ...
a = (b = (c = 10));

Also, although that is valid and well-defined, I am among many programmers who would advise you that concatenated assignments like that (either form) are poor style.

What your teacher said is correct, but only if you read it in a special way.
An assignment in C is an expression, because you can say f( x = 5 ), in which case 5 gets assigned to x, but then the whole x = 5 thing is an expression which evaluates to 5, and then the value of that expression gets passed as a parameter to function f().
Be advised that most programmers would consider this construct confusing, and in most places it would not pass code review.
Similarly, people often do if( booleanVariable = booleanFunction() ) { ... } which invokes a function and assigns the result to a variable, and then this assignment expression evaluates to the assigned value, which is then checked by the if statement.  This is also considered confusing, albeit a bit less because it is used very often.
Now, this would also be an expression in C:
5

And by writing a semi-colon after it, you can use it as a statement, as follows:
printf( "Hello, " );
5;
printf( " world!" );

This may be nonsensical, but it is valid C. It should produce warning "statement has no effect", but the fact is, if you ignore warnings, this compiles and runs just fine.  (If it does not produce a warning, then this means that you are trying to write code without first having figured out how to enable all warnings on your compiler, which is highly inadvisable, but that's a different story.)
The reason for this weirdness in C is that the syntax of the language was designed in such a way as to allow for a very simple compiler.
The language wanted to allow invoking a function and ignoring its return value, (for example, doSomething();) which means that the language has to allow free-standing function invocations.
However, a function invocation must also be an expression, so that you can do f( doSomething() );, so, since function invocations can be free standing, and since they are expressions, this means that the compiler needs to allow free-standing expressions.
The semi-colon is necessary for the compiler to be able to tell where the single-expression-used-as-a-statement ends, and the next statement begins.

Some would suggest if (function_call() == var) { ... } precisely because if (function_call() = vr) { ... } will yield an error while if (var = function_call()) { ... } will compile.
